# RequestDispatcher for an input form

Tags: java, forms, requestdispatcher

```
<form id='search' method='get'>
<input type='text' name='search' />
<input type='submit' value='Search'/><br/>
</form>
```

I have this search form.

```
String search = request.getParameter("search");
    if (search != null) {
                request.setAttribute("search", search);
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Content");
                rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

And here I want to get what I type in the input and dispatch it to the Content. My input is not reaction at all. My debugger shows that my programm doesnt even go to the request.getParameter("search") part. Whats the problem?

Comment: change this  <input type='text' name='search' /> to <input type='text' name='search' id='search' />

Comment: By the way: Is name the Parameter I have to reffer to ? or is it Id? ( i mean in getParamter("search") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the action name in form like below:

```
<form action="/yourServlet/"id='search' method='get'>
<input type='text' name='search' />
<input type='submit' value='Search'/><br/>
</form>
```

**Servlet Code:**

```
    public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet{

        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   
        response) throws IOException{
           String search = request.getParameter("search");
              if (search != null) {
                 request.setAttribute("search", search);
                RequestDispatcher rd =  
                  request.getRequestDispatcher("Content");
                rd.forward(request, response);
    }
        }
    }
```

**And servlet mapping in your web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.YourServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/yourServlet/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I added action to my form. now I get a result. The problem is that it is in my search iframe. but i want it in my content iframe.

Comment: This problem needs another question